# Jersey/JAX-RS WriterInterceptor and HTTP Status

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, http-status-codes, inject, servlet-container

I have a problem with Jersey, I am writing a `WriterInterceptor` which should save the answer to the database, the problem is that I cannot retrieve the httpstatus, to avoid saving the answer in case of an error, I tried `@Context HttpServletResponse` but the status is 200 when it becomes 500 shortly after, how can I inject 'Response'? Or `ContainerResponse`/`ContainerResponseContext`?

Comment: Try to inject `javax.inject.Provider<ContainerResponse>`

Comment: I have tried with  `@Inject private javax.inject.Provider<ContainerResponse> response;` `ContainerResponse r = response.get();` but r is null. It's incredible, in the `WriterInterceptor` I can have everything but not `Response` !!!

Comment: Do I need to register something?

Comment: No, Jersey would have to do this binding with the injector. I don't remember if I have ever had to inject the ContainerRequest so I wasn't sure if it was possible. Did you try with ContainerResponseContext? I would imagine if ContainerResponse didn't work, then this wouldn't either though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes I also tried with `ContainerResponseContext`, but it doesn't work. I don't want to move into the filter, I only have the Java object in the filter.

Comment: My issue on GitHub ... [4746](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4746)